# Lucene search for Longest Common Substring

Tags: java, elasticsearch, solr, lucene

I am using Lucene 6.0.0 and guess that my problem can be solved by `FuzzuQuery` provided `editDistance > 2` would have been supported in Lucene.

I am using plain Java Lucene API ( Nor SOLR or ElasticSearch ).

Lets say non - tokenized indexed text filed is - `This is Ram's House` and when I search with `Ram` or `ram` , I should get `This is Ram's House` as a match because three continuous characters matched so in a sense - this is kind of fuzzy match requirement with more than two edit distance.

Searching with `My name is Ram and my brother's name is Shyam` should also give me `This is Ram's House` as a match.

There can be a restriction on minimum number of characters in **Longest Common Substring** and currently we should be fine with three as limit.

As per our analysis, there is a business problem that can be solved this way.

Is it possible with Lucene?

Doable with any other tools - like SOLR, ElasticSearch etc?

Comment: Both of your examples should work just fine with typical analysis without using FuzzyQueries at all. What is the problem you are running into?

Comment: What do you mean? I am using `StandardAnalyzer` and not tokenizing text field while indexing. I get no matches with `FuzzyQuery` , `WildCardQuery` , `TermQuery` or `PhraseQuery` so I am not sure as what needs to be changed on indexing side and which kind of query to used on searcher side.

Comment: Right, of course not, it isn't tokenized. So... why aren't you tokenizing that field?

Comment: because I am looking for N continuous characters which might be spread across multiple words e.g. when I search for `sram` for `This is Ram's House` , I should get a match even though `s` is part of `is`. I will update my question with a little bit of code that I tried.I guess, if I tokenize, there would be different terms for each word.

Comment: Also, my indexed data might be all numeric ( without any letters ) without any spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to solve this problem by using N-Gram Indexing technique in lucene by using - [NGramTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenizer.html)

I choose `minGram` & `maxGram` values as per my requirement and I have sub strings ready as indexed and I can query index for those terms.

It increases number of generated and indexed terms greatly but solves my problem.

[More Explanation here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ngrams_for_partial_matching.html)